# What does NFSv4 "domain name" have to be set to?

Tags: domain, nfs

Other than "the same for the client AND the server", does the NFSv4 domain name have to be set to anything in particular?

I mean, does it have to be some domain in my LAN or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it doesn't have to be set to anything particular. However, it makes sense to choose a DNS domain name that would uniquely identify a user account (username@domain) just like an e-mail address does.

Comment: Thanks - a very clear answer. The whole "domain" bit threw me I think. Perhaps they should call it a "zone" or something ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Actually, NFSv4 *will* default to your DNS domain if not otherwise specified, and machines in a different DNS domain won't be able to mount the share.  In that sense, the use of the word domain does make some sense.